# Regular expression to check "@" at the beginning of a word and it should be only once in a word

Tags: regex, autocomplete

I need to match the @ symbol using a regex. I've tried the regex `/\B@(\w*)$/`. It is working but my use case is @ should appear only once in the beginning of a word. Not more than once:

```
@test - Right one.
@@test - Not a right one.
```

Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Kurshith/deepk1dm/1/. When you type @ on the text area, it will trigger the auto-complete. But it will allow even if you type @ twice.  But in my case,  It should allow only for @test, @test @hello, @. Please help me.

Comment: What exactly do you need the `\B` for in your regex? In `@@test` the first ampersand is  matched by it... See [RegEx101](https://regex101.com/r/lX7bQ1/1) BTW: If you want to hold the words at least one more character, you should require it using `\w+`.

Comment: Need more clarity and few more examples.

Comment: Do you need to match:  "This is a @test," or will you have only one-"word" match subjects?  In regex terms, '@' is not a word character, so it can't be part of the word; however, it can abut a word, e.g.: "word1@word2."  It's important to discern because in regex terms, that would be a match because '@' is at the beginning of a word, "word2," and there is only one @.  If you're talking awk-type words, then it should fail because the '@' is in the middle of 'word1@word2'. Your example is not anchored and uses regex word \w, so implies 'word1@word2' should match. Please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

`/^@[^@]*$/` will do.  Your case can be stated as: begin with `@` and then anything else that is not `@` with 0 or more occurrences, and until the end of the string.

Testing with Ruby's `irb`:

```
irb(main):003:0> /^@[^@]*$/.match("@test")
=> #<MatchData "@test">

irb(main):004:0> /^@[^@]*$/.match("@@test")
=> nil

irb(main):005:0> /^@[^@]*$/.match("@test@")
=> nil

irb(main):006:0> /^@[^@]*$/.match("@test@test")
=> nil

irb(main):007:0> /^@[^@]*$/.match("test")
=> nil

irb(main):008:0> /^@[^@]*$/.match("t@est")
=> nil

irb(main):009:0> /^@[^@]*$/.match("@")
=> #<MatchData "@">

irb(main):010:0> /^@[^@]*$/.match("@@")
=> nil
```

Comment: Good answer so long as his entire subject is one "word."  Otherwise the anchor will get you in trouble.  It will not match this:  "now is the @time."

Comment: Thanks Guys. It is not solving the problem. I have updated question with a fiddle link. Please check it and help me.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a whitespace boundary. Add anchors as necessary.

`(?<!\S)@(\w*)(?!\S)`